# How to determine the proper order/buffer for StdOut and StdError

Tags: delphi, console, console-application, pipe

I have an external console application I would like to capture it's **complete** output (StdOut and StdError) in real time to a memo (just as if I would double click it).

Infos about the application with screenshots:
[Delphi Console pipes switched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122084/delphi-console-pipes-switched)

I've written an unit to read the pipes:

```
unit uConsoleOutput;
interface

uses  Classes,
      StdCtrls,
      SysUtils,
      Messages,
      Windows;

  type
  ConsoleThread = class(TThread)
  private
    OutputString : String;
    procedure SetOutput;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    App           : WideString;
    Memo          : TMemo;
    Directory     : WideString;
  end;

  type
    PConsoleData = ^ConsoleData;
    ConsoleData = record
    OutputMemo          : TMemo;
    OutputApp           : WideString;
    OutputDirectory     : WideString;
    OutputThreadHandle  : ConsoleThread;
  end;

function StartConsoleOutput (App : WideString; Directory : WideString; Memo : TMemo) : PConsoleData;
procedure StopConsoleOutput  (Data : PConsoleData);

implementation

procedure ConsoleThread.SetOutput;
begin
  Memo.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  Memo.Text := Memo.Text + OutputString;
  Memo.Lines.EndUpdate;
end;

procedure ConsoleThread.Execute;
const
  ReadBuffer = 50;
var
  Security    : TSecurityAttributes;
  InputPipeRead,
  InputPipeWrite,
  OutputPipeRead,
  OutputPipeWrite,
  ErrorPipeRead,
  ErrorPipeWrite : THandle;
  start       : TStartUpInfo;
  ProcessInfo : TProcessInformation;
  Buffer      : Pchar;
  BytesRead   : DWord;
  Apprunning  : DWord;
begin
  Security.nlength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes) ;
  Security.lpsecuritydescriptor := nil;
  Security.binherithandle := true;
  if Createpipe (InputPipeRead, InputPipeWrite, @Security, 0) then begin
    if CreatePipe(OutputPipeRead, OutputPipeWrite, @Security, 0) then begin
      if CreatePipe(ErrorPipeRead, ErrorPipeWrite, @Security, 0) then begin
        Buffer := AllocMem(ReadBuffer + 1) ;
        FillChar(Start,Sizeof(Start),#0) ;
        start.cb := SizeOf(start) ;
        start.hStdOutput  := OutputPipeWrite;
        start.hStdError   := ErrorPipeWrite;
        start.hStdInput   := InputPipeRead;
        start.dwFlags     := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES + STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
        start.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
        if CreateProcessW(nil,pwidechar(APP),@Security,@Security,true,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,nil,pwidechar(Directory),start,ProcessInfo) then begin
          while not(terminated) do begin

          // ====> Stuck here.
            // ReadErrorPipe
            BytesRead := 0;
            if Terminated then break;
            ReadFile(ErrorPipeRead,Buffer[0], ReadBuffer,BytesRead,nil);
            if Terminated then break;
            Buffer[BytesRead]:= #0;
            if Terminated then break;
            //OemToAnsi(Buffer,Buffer);
            if Terminated then break;
            OutputString := Buffer;
            if Terminated then break;
            Synchronize(SetOutput);

            // ReadStdOut
            BytesRead := 0;
            if Terminated then break;
            ReadFile(OutputPipeRead,Buffer[0], ReadBuffer,BytesRead,nil);
            if Terminated then break;
            Buffer[BytesRead]:= #0;
            if Terminated then break;
            //OemToAnsi(Buffer,Buffer);
            if Terminated then break;
            OutputString := Buffer;
            if Terminated then break;
            Synchronize(SetOutput);

            end;
          FreeMem(Buffer);
          CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
          CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
          CloseHandle(InputPipeRead);
          CloseHandle(InputPipeWrite);
          CloseHandle(OutputPipeRead);
          CloseHandle(OutputPipeWrite);
          CloseHandle(ErrorPipeRead);
          CloseHandle(ErrorPipeWrite);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function StartConsoleOutput (App : WideString; Directory : WideString; Memo : TMemo) : PConsoleData;
begin
  result                          := VirtualAlloc(NIL, SizeOf(ConsoleData), MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
  Memo.DoubleBuffered             := TRUE;
  with PConsoleData(result)^ do begin
    OutputMemo                          := Memo;
    OutputApp                           := App;
    OutputDirectory                     := Directory;
    OutputThreadHandle                  := ConsoleThread.Create(TRUE);
    OutputThreadHandle.FreeOnTerminate  := TRUE;
    OutputThreadHandle.Memo             := Memo;
    OutputThreadHandle.App              := App;
    OutputThreadHandle.Directory        := Directory;
    OutputThreadHandle.Resume;
  end;
end;

procedure StopConsoleOutput  (Data : PConsoleData);
begin
  with PConsoleData(Data)^ do begin
    OutputThreadHandle.Terminate;
    while not(OutputThreadHandle.Terminated) do sleep (100);
  end;
  VirtualFree (Data,0, MEM_RELEASE);
end;

end.
```

I start applications like this:

```
StartConsoleOutput ('C:\myexternalapp.exe', 'C:\', Memo1);
```

I would like to ouput the stderror first and then the stdoutput (or at least in an order that reads 1:1 what the console outputs)
The problem is the order and the proper buffersize.

How do I read these 2 pipes in the right order and with which buffer size to accomplish an 1:1 output?

Comment: Why don't you write both stderr and stdout to the same pipe?

Comment: I tried but it looks like there is something missing. Would that be hstdouterror := OutputPipeWrite ?

Comment: Yep. Two pipes rather than three. And whatever you assign to stdout, you assign to stderr. Sorry can't help more, going out.

Comment: I tried but I guess it's the application that is messed up... I can't catch all of the output of it. I even used buffersize 1.

Comment: This "solution" will also cause that the pipes are switched and the output is reversed.

Comment: Why downvote? Is there something wrong?

Comment: If you map both stdout and stderr to the same pipe, there will be no switching. I think it's the only way to be sure that information arrives in the same order that it was sent. I cannot understand your use VirtualAlloc. You can declare a variable of your record type in the thread class.

Comment: Yeah I already changed it and completely removed my record. It returns the TThread now which has public vars. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`PeekNamedPipe()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365779.aspx) to determine when a pipe has data available for reading and how many bytes can be read.  Despite its name, it works with both named pipes and anonymous pipes.

Comment: This would do the trick! But you need to add sleep or it will eat a lot of CPU power if you always check with PeekNamedPipe.