# Getting output from a command-line program in a Delphi application on Windows XP

Tags: delphi, command-line, windows-xp

I have VCL application written in Delphi XE2 that needs to execute a command-line program (also written in Delphi XE2) and obtain the text output by it. I am currently using the following code, which is based on that found here: [Getting output from a shell/dos app into a Delphi app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119999/getting-output-from-a-shell-dos-app-into-a-delphi-app/9120103#9120103)

```
function GetDosOutput(ACommandLine : string; AWorkingDirectory : string): string;
var
  SecurityAttributes : TSecurityAttributes;
  StartupInfo : TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInformation: TProcessInformation;
  StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite: THandle;
  WasOK: Boolean;
  Buffer: array[0..255] of AnsiChar;
  BytesRead: Cardinal;
  Handle: Boolean;
begin
  Result := '';
  SecurityAttributes.nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
  SecurityAttributes.bInheritHandle := True;
  SecurityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
  CreatePipe(StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite, @SecurityAttributes, 0);
  try
    FillChar(StartupInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), 0);
    StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
    StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
    StartupInfo.hStdInput := StdOutPipeRead;
    StartupInfo.hStdOutput := StdOutPipeWrite;
    StartupInfo.hStdError := StdOutPipeWrite;
    FillChar(ProcessInformation, SizeOf(ProcessInformation), 0);
    Handle := CreateProcess(
      nil,
      PChar(ACommandLine),
      nil,
      nil,
      True,
      0,
      nil,
      PChar(AWorkingDirectory),
      StartupInfo,
      ProcessInformation
    );
    CloseHandle(StdOutPipeWrite);
    if Handle then
      try
        repeat
          WasOK := ReadFile(StdOutPipeRead, Buffer, 255, BytesRead, nil);
          if BytesRead > 0 then
          begin
            Buffer[BytesRead] := #0;
            Result := Result + Buffer;
          end;
        until not WasOK or (BytesRead = 0);
        WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInformation.hProcess, INFINITE);
      finally
        CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hThread);
        CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hProcess);
      end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(StdOutPipeRead);
  end;
end;
```

This works fine on most versions of Windows. Unfortunately it has recently come to our attention that it does not work on Windows XP. The call to WaitForSingleObject simply never returns. I tried replacing the second parameter INFINITE with a smaller value (e.g. 15000) but that doesnt't seem to make any difference. In Task Manager I can see that, after calling GetDosOutput, the command-line program is actually running. If I end the VCL application, the command-line program *then* seems to complete its work successfully (as evidenced by the fact that it outputs the files I was expecting it to). I've also noticed that if I remove STARTF_USESTDHANDLES from StartupInfo.dwFlags, the command-line program runs normally and WaitForSingleObject returns promptly; however I am then obviously unable to obtain the text returned by the program.

Does anybody have a suggestion as to how I can get this working on Windows XP?

Comment: You can find correct code in answer to following task:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119999/getting-output-from-a-shell-dos-app-into-a-delphi-app/9120103#9120103

Comment: I enjoyed reading this bit: Handle: Boolean

Comment: @DavidHeffernan For people with a strongly typed background the BOOL type of the winAPI can be confusing.

Comment: @mg30rg C is a strongly typed language. It just has not had a boolean type until recent times.

Comment: Maybe this helps too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123427/how-to-determine-the-proper-order-buffer-for-stdout-and-stderror

Comment: @HughJones It's not using cmd.

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn Thanks for the hint :) Actually I had seen that post (I even linked to it in my original question), and I *thought* I had read it carefully enough. But it turns out there is a subtle difference between the two code snippets in Uwe Raabe's answer: in the first, WaitForSingleObject is called before ReadFile, in the second, it is the other way around (as in my code). So I swapped these around in my code, and now it works on both Windows XP and Windows 7!

Comment: @JanDoggen Interesting link :) I've got my code working now (as mentioned above), but thanks for the help.

Comment: If you wait for the program to finish before reading the pipe, you can get deadlock. It's better to read the output as it becomes available. In that respect your code from Delphi Dabbler is better. Investigate more into why the program appears to hang. Use a debugger.

Comment: Come on, this smelly piece of code originates from the about.com and has been crititized and reviewed many times.

Comment: @Free, this code appears to come from Delphi Dabbler; see the linked answer by Uwe to compare the two. Could you give some links to critiques of *this* code?

Comment: @RobKennedy, you are right, precisely this one appears to be one of numerous derivatives (not 100% the same as DelphiDabler's snippet too). Anyway, I'd suggest to stop flogging a dead horse and move onto JCL helper (or corresponding JVCL component).

Comment: @RobKennedy Ok, thanks for the warning about potential deadlocks.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Thanks, I didn't know that you could do this with JCL. So I can just use TJclCommandLineTool, and that should work on all versions of Windows without the risk of deadlocks as mentioned in Rob Kennedy's post?

Comment: It is indeed much more reliable than code snippet from the internet.

Comment: @FreeConsulting, that comment (slightly expanded) should really be an answer.

Comment: this solution freezes in case if the command being executed doesn't end. 
Better solution described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723807/execute-dos-program-and-get-output-dynamically

Answer (score 7):

There is a really useful unit in freepascal called "process", which does just that, and, work has been done to **port** it **to Delphi** so you can capture the output of a command in **Delphi** using a simple one liner:

`RunCommand()`

Or you can capture the output of the command with more advanced features by creating a TProcess object yourself (which RunCommand just wraps).

The project is here:

- https://github.com/z505/TProcess-Delphi
- A simple demo: https://github.com/z505/TProcess-Delphi/tree/master/demo-simple

How to capture the output of a command, i.e. "dir" (list directory contents, famous MS DOS command) into a string then add it to a memo:

```
uses 
  dprocess; 
// ...
var 
  output: ansistring;
begin
  RunCommand('cmd', ['/c', 'dir'], output, [poNoConsole]);
  memo1.Lines.Add(output);
end;
```

Comment: Are you going to post the same answer to every question mentioning ShellExecute?